# NFS problem with Ubuntu server and Xubuntu fstab - first try always fails

Tags: xubuntu, nfs

after looking over the Internet for hours I'm experiencing a most peculiar effect running Ubuntu Server 14.04.2 and Xubuntu 14.04 as client.

I've set up an NFS server, shared the paths to the correct IP addresses, done the "exportfs -ra" and rebooted the machine.

On the client, I have following line on my `fstab`:

```
192.xx.1.xx:/media/data/shared  /media/Share    nfs rw,noauto,async,users   0   0
```

and an unmounted "Share" folder appears on the desktop. So far so good. Here comes the weirdness. If I try to open the "Share" folder on the desktop, the timeout message appears. But, the server folder was mounted successfully! If browse to `/media/Share` on the client, the contents are accessible. If I unmount it using `umount`, and I click on the desktop icon again, the folder is mounted and visible on the file manager.

When I reboot the system, again the same.

If I reboot the system and immediately after that I do a command line mount, it works perfect. I can then unmount per command line and mount graphically, and it works.

It's always the first try, using the `fstab` entry and the file manager which results in timeout.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out after some looking around.

Turns out Ubuntu 14.04 server defaults to NFSv4, and as I read in a few posts, there's apparently a bug where NFSv4, regardless of configurations, tries to activate/enable Kerberos.

Disabling NFSv4 and defaulting it to NFSv3 did the trick for me. I found out about this [in this article](http://andy.delcambre.com/2007/06/25/disabling-nfsv4-on-ubuntu.html) which explains the procedure:

> Edit `/etc/default/nfs-kernel-server` to include:
>
> ```
> # Number of servers to start up
> RPCNFSDCOUNT='8 --no-nfs-version 4'
> ```
>
> (Eight is the default number of servers)